# How to consider precision in another column while applying round(precision) to the value column in Dataframe, Python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have DataFrame with Column: precision & value; precision contains integer values like 1, 2, 3-decimal places to pass in round function. How to pass "precision" field while performing round to each value? For every value I have to apply round as per field "precision".

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[15.5666, 2], [14.32, 1], [14.68954, 3], [16.78, 1]], columns=['value', 'precision'])

df['value2'] = df['value'].round(df['precision'])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometime for loop is not bad

```
[round(x, y) for x , y in zip(df['value'], df['precision'])]
Out[128]: [15.57, 14.3, 14.69, 16.8]
#df['value2'] = [round(x, y) for x , y in zip(df['value'], df['precision'])]
```

Comment: can we strip zero at the end of Decimal value; like round(14.32000, 1) - give 14.30, can we keep 14.3 Only?

Comment: @SPy how about convert it to str ?, If numeric, pandas object will make all column in same format